# How to connect to Azure Artifacts on Mac

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to connect to Azure Artificats on Mac by following this doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=linux%2Cclassic

Since I am on Mac, I followed the 'Mac' tab in the Credentials setup.

But when I run 'npm install', I still get a 401, The error message is

```
56 verbose stack HttpErrorAuthUnknown: Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47, Basic realm="https://pkgsprodsu3weu.app.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", TFS-Federated
```

Then I try using 'better-vsts-npm-auth', I see the .npmrc has an '_authToken' for the registry that I need to npm. But when I run 'npm install', I still get a 401.

```
56 verbose stack HttpErrorAuthUnknown: Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer
```

Can u tell me how can I config my npmrc to download npms?

Thank you.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can firstly delete `.npmrc` file in your folder.

Then re-configure `.npmrc` file using the following command:

```
npx vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc
```

In some case, instead of using `npm install`, you can use

`Use npm install --registry https://registry.npmjs.org`

to solve the 401 error.

Comment: This is not working on Mac per documentation.